# A short question regarding Ampère's law

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electric-current

Suppose I have path of integration  enclosing 3 wires, each one of them carrying the same magnitude of current (let's call it **I**) but two of them are outward the page while the other is inward. This is the situation depicted in the following picture:

[image]

where the red path is the path of integration. My question is if the enclosed current is **Ienc = I** since one of the outward current gets compensated by its counterpart going inward.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ampere's law is:

$$ \oint_C \mathbf{B} \cdot \mathrm{d}\mathbf{\ell} = \mu_0 I_{\text{enclosed by $C$}}. $$

If your three wires in the red contour all contribute the same magnitude $I$, then yes two of them will cancel out to give you a *net* $I_{\text{enclosed by $C$}} = I$.

However, the *field* will be in a non-trivial direction, so $\mathbf{B} \cdot \mathrm{d}\mathbf{\ell}$ will not simplify easily as it would for a single current-carrying wire.